# Android views that can be popped up wherever from application

Tags: android, popup, material-design, toast

I have an app that recieves push messages from Google Cloud Messaging.

So when the app is not visible user recieves Notification. If app is visible user recieves Toast. But want to try more interesting solutions if they are exist.

So the question is what views in Android could be called from any Activity of the app like this happens when we use Toast?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You can create a [custom Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)

Comment: Will this allow to attach, for instance, a Floating Action Button?

Comment: Something which looks like a FAB? Sure. But a Toast is not clickable. If you want something clickable, use a DialogFragment and dismiss it after some time has passed

Comment: Oh, thank u for answering a lot!
Isn't it possible to set onClickListener for Toast elements?
So the function is like:
1. I recieve push from GCM - > 
2. Something appear on screen, doesnt matter what activity I'm currently in ->
3. This have options to skip appeared view or to click to invoke some action. Is it possible with Dialog Fragment. The key question - what view in android can be invoked from any part (activity) of the app?

Comment: First: you don't invoke a View. A Toast contains a View. So does a Dialog or a Snackbar. Second: the "something" you seem to be looking for could be a Snackbar or if you need a custom look better a DialogFragment. Skipping a DialogFragment is possible by tapping somewhere outside its area or by pressing BACK. In addition to that, you could imitate the self-dismissing behavior of a Snackbar or a Toast by using postDelayed(). My suggestion: start experimenting. If you get stuck somewhere specific, ask a new question containing some code and people will try to help you with the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is no legal way to do what I wanted. It's possible to invoke AlertDialog, but it will block the current activity. To not block the activity, we can still use Toasts, even custom, but without possibility to make it stay on the screen.

But the best solution is to do nothing, but leave notifications only, doesnt metter if app is visible or not.